# How to choose colors wisely to work with Low brightness and contrast screens?

Tags: website-design, mobile, color-combination

In Mobile Phone and Tablets to save battery many people (Including me) keep brightness and contrast low. And sometime it makes harder to read if color scheme is not good.
So my question is how to choose good color scheme for Mobile website and apps to work well in Low brightness and contrast condition.

Any tips?

**Note:** I'm not asking for High contrast color schemes for low vision people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My experience has been that generally if a color scheme passes the color blindness and *luminosity* tests for usability, they work well on mobile too, no matter the users' settings.  I like to run my colors through the luminosity analyzers before selecting the final versions.

There are several online tools like at the [Paciellogroup](http://www.paciellogroup.com/resources/contrast-analyser.html) or [Juicy Studio](http://juicystudio.com/services/luminositycontrastratio.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use one very strong solid color for main elements: black, blue, red, etc

And one very soft color, with not much saturation for the background: white, tan, or any color set to a very pale hue or saturation.